# Is block: (canvas: Canvas) -> Unit equivalent to block: Canvas.() -> Unit in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I see Code B frequently, and I see Code A seldom.

Is Code A correct?

Is `block: (canvas: Canvas) -> Unit` equivalent to `block: Canvas.() -> Unit` in Kotlin?

**Code A**

```
fun DrawScope.drawNormal(block: (canvas: Canvas) -> Unit) {
    drawIntoCanvas {
        block(it)
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
fun DrawScope.drawNormal(block: Canvas.() -> Unit) {
    drawIntoCanvas {
        block(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code A declare a function who takes a Canvas as parameters.
You'll be able to use Canvas using `it` or by naming it.

```kotlin
drawNormal { canvas ->
// do whatever you want with canvas
}
```

In code B you are using (like @gidds said) a [function literal with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver). You provide a scope where the anonymous function will be running. So in the anonymous function, the `this` will be the canvas.

```kotlin
drawNormal {
// no parameters, you can simply use all canvas functions in this block
}
```

Both approach are good but it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

It's like scoped functions with `let` and `apply`

The code A will be better if you just want to get canvas attributes like width and length to build another things or do some actions with it.

The code B will be better if you want to **modify** the canvas reference (like modifying width and length)

Comment: Code A doesn't declare an anonymous function. The function has the name `block` and is an argument to `drawNormal`. Callers of code A may choose to use an anonymous function, or a lambda, or a function reference

Answer (score 2):

They are not equivalent from the point of view of the caller of your function.

In Code A, `block` is a function that takes the `Canvas` as an *argument*. This means that the caller of `drawNormal` will access it as `it` or via a named parameter in the lambda:

```kotlin
drawNormal {
    it.rotate(90f)
}

drawNormal { canvas ->
    canvas.rotate(90f)
}
```

In Code B, `block` is a function that takes a `Canvas` as a *receiver*. This means that the caller will access it as `this` or call functions from `Canvas` directly:

```kotlin
drawNormal {
    this.rotate(90f)
    rotate(90f)
}
```

Both are equally correct. It depends on the experience you want to provide to your caller.